# I can't create files or directories in android studio with kotlin

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I need to create a text file in my Android app but it won't let me. The method of verifying that it has been created returns me fake. How could I do that?

I already assigned write permissions on the application manifest.xml but it doesn't work for me either.
I also made the request for permissions.

The permissions on manifest.xml I assigned like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The code to write the file, I did it this way:

```
    fun writeFile() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@GenerateCodeActivity,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        }

        val sd_main = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath+"/FilesMyApp")
        var success = true
        if (!sd_main.exists()) {
            success = sd_main.mkdir()
        }
        if (success) {
            val sd = File("${this@GenerateCodeActivity.auth.currentUser?.uid}")
            val hola = "HOLA QUE TAL"
            if (!sd.exists()) {
                success = sd.mkdir()
            }
            if (success) {
                // directory exists or already created
                val dest = File(sd, "${this@GenerateCodeActivity.auth.currentUser?.uid}.txt")
                try {
                    // response is the data written to file
                    FileOutputStream(dest).use { it.write(hola.toByteArray()) }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    // handle the exception
                }

            } else {
                // directory creation is not successful
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to type the indicated text string, but it won't let me enter the "if (success)" zone.

Comment: `requestPermissions()` is not a blocking call. You will not yet have the permission by the time that returns.

Comment: How could I do that? Wouldn't it be necessary to have put in the manifest.xml what I've indicated anyway? The truth is, I'm new to android programming.

Comment: Yes, you need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest. You need to move your I/O work to a separate function, calling it from two places. One is if `checkSelfPermission()` says that you already have permission. The other is from your `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback, if you determine that you were granted the permission. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.

Comment: I've done everything you've told me, but I still can't do it. I have included that in the manifest, I have made the writing request and I have created the method of ```onRequestPermissionsResult()``` It still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
val sd = File("${this@GenerateCodeActivity.auth.currentUser?.uid}")
```

You have not specified a directory. Use:

```
val sd = File(sd_main, "${this@GenerateCodeActivity.auth.currentUser?.uid}")
```